# Does removing docker image affect the caching

Tags: docker, jenkins, caching

At the end of a Jenkins pipeline there is a
`sh "docker image rm #{IMAGE_ID_HERE}"`
I noticed that on each build the cache is not utilized, and all the steps are executed again. Could this be the reason why the cache is not utilized?

Comment: can you be more clear about what steps are running again ? if you are talking about image build step then yep this step is the reason.

Comment: Yes it's build step. Basically it's running ```npm install``` on each build. I will verify this and provide more information. Mind if you post this as an answer, so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker image rm` command will delete the image build during pipeline. for that reason when you delete the image, next time the image will be build again when it comes to `docker build` command.
So in this case, **Yes** this command is the reason for not caching docker image for next build.

If you want to use cache for docker steps please use `docker build` command with `--cache-from` option, and remove this command. i-e `docker image rm`

I assume you are deleting the image at the end of pipeline, just to free space and resources, I would suggest not to delete them after every build, but run a cron job in your build agent that runs at stipulated time e.g maybe every night at 12AM and in that cron job you can run `docker image prune` command which will delete all unused/dangling images.

Comment: I do exactly the same but I check for space and I run the 'docker image prune -af' command in the cron only when space drops at 20%, This way I get to reuse the cache most of the time and only purge it when I risk to remain without free space. Also good Idea is to run the command when there is no usage (night time)

Comment: yep, this works great with build agents running too many jobs.

Comment: Just to share my solution on deleting the image:     

`docker image rm \$(docker image ls $REGISTRY | grep $PROJECT_NAME-$PARSED_ENVIRONMENT | tail +2 | awk '{ print \$3 }')`

This will keep 1 image